# Prevent default behaviour of Alt-Tab and start button in Metro app

Tags: windows-8, winjs

Is there a way to capture Alt-Tab and start button so that their action is not captured by the system?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows-embedded/archive/2013/10/16/windows-embedded-8-1-assigned-access-and-windows-embedded-lockdown.aspx might be what you really want.

Comment: +1 I think this is a valid question. PCs at public places require this "Assign Access" feature.

Comment: I want Alt-Tab and start button to work in a metro app where I have a remote desktop. 
Therefore my problem is that when pressing alt-tab in the remote desktop, Alt-Tab buttons works for the local system.

Comment: @kiewic for Public PCs you can use Assigned Access, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hyperyash/archive/2013/10/25/enable-kiosk-mode-in-windows-8-1.aspx